# Cannot identify this insect

Tags: species-identification, entomology

Can anyone please help identify this insect. It seems to be some sort of caterpillar but I'm stumped.

- Location is in Suffolk, United Kingdom
- Length is around 1cm, width is perhaps 4 or 5mm.

[image: Insect]

Image opens a video clip on YouTube.

Comment: Is there a way to embed the video into the question?

Comment: There are a number of larvae that glue detritus to their backs. I'm not sure what this one is.

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE! For identification questions please [edit](https://biology.stackexchange.com/posts/86437/edit) your post to: 1) include the location (e.g. country and region — the more specific the better), and 2) an estimate of the size of the creature. The location and size can be essential clues for identification. ——— If possible a clear, closeup photo would also be helpful. ——— Please also take the time to take the [tour] and then the help pages starting with [Ask] questions effectively on this site. Thanks! 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That appears to a "[bag worm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bagworm_moth)", which is as you surmised a caterpillar.

This suggest that it is from the family Psychidae, but I won't even try to guess at the species.  However, if you see any adults you may be able to identify them using [this website](https://ukmoths.org.uk/thumbnails/psychidae).

An example image of an North American species:

[image: bagworm image ©2004 Tony DiTerlizzi from: https://bugguide.net/node/view/8832]

Comment: Thank you. After viewing some videos of this bag worm / case worm moth, it seems to appear, and also move in the same manner. Case closed!